# Having child-processes allow rpc-server to restart while children survive

Tags: python, linux, sockets, multiprocessing, simplexmlrpcserver

**Scenario**

I have a rpc-server that needs to spawn important processes (`multiprocessing.Process`) that last for several days. For security/safety reasons, I don't want these processes survival to depend on the rpc-server. Therfore, I want the server to be able to die *and be able to reboot* while the processes are running.

**Orphaning processes**

This problem is solvable by (*don't paste it where you don't want to loose previous work, it will close your python session*):

```
import os
import multiprocessing
import time

def _job(data):
    for _ in range(3):
        print multiprocessing.current_process(), "is working"
        time.sleep(2)
    print multiprocessing.current_process(), "is done"

#My real worker gets a Connection-object as part of a
#multiprocessing.Pipe among other arguments
worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=_job, args=(None,))
worker.daemon = True
worker.start()
os._exit(0)
```

**Problem: Closing the socket of the rpc-server if worker is alive**

Exiting the main process seems not to aid or effect the closing of the socket-issue. So for illustrating the problem the server reboot, it is simulated with starting a second server with identical parameters after the first has been *closed*.

The following works perfectly:

```
import SimpleXMLRPCServer
HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 45212
s = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer((HOST, PORT))
s.server_close()
s = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer((HOST, PORT))
s.server_close()
```

However, if a worker is created, it raises a `socket.error` saying the socket is already in use:

```
s = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer((HOST, PORT))
worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=_job, args=(None,))
worker.start()
s.server_close()
s = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer((HOST, PORT)) #raises socket.error
worker.join()
s.server_close()
```

A manual closing of the servers socket does work:

```
import socket
s = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer((HOST, PORT))
worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=_job, args=(None,))
worker.start()
s.socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
s = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer((HOST, PORT))
worker.join()
s.server_close()
```

But this behavior really worries me. I don't pass the socket in any way to the worker, but it appears as if it gets a hold of it anyhow.

There are similar questions previously posted, but they tend to pass the socket through to the worker, which is not intended here. If I send the socket through though, I can close it in the worker and get around the `shutdown` hack:

```
def _job2(notMySocket):
    notMySocket.close()
    for _ in range(3):
        print multiprocessing.current_process(), "is working"
        time.sleep(2)
    print multiprocessing.current_process(), "is done"

s = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer((HOST, PORT))
worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=_job2, args=(s.socket,))
worker.start()
time.sleep(0.1) #Just to be sure worker gets to close socket in time
s.server_close()
s = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer((HOST, PORT)) 
worker.join()
s.server_close()
```

But the server's socket has absolutely no reason to visit the worker. I don't like this solution a bit, even if it's the best one so far.

**Question**

Is there a way of limiting what gets forked when using `multiprocessing.Process` so only that which I want to pass to the target gets copied, and not all open sockets and other stuff?

In my case, to get this code working:

```
s = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer((HOST, PORT))
childPipe, parentPipe = multiprocessing.Pipe()
worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=_job, args=(childPipe,))
worker.start()
s.server_close()
s = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer((HOST, PORT)) #raises socket.error
worker.join()
s.server_close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Python 2.x, I don't think there's any way to avoid that inheritence on Posix platforms. `os.fork` will always be used to create the new process, which means the entire state of the parent process will be copied to the child. All you can do is immediately close the socket in the child, which is what you're already doing. The only way you could avoid this inheritence is by starting the processes *before* you start the server. You may be able to do this by starting the `Process` early and then using a `multiprocessing.Queue` to deliver work items (instead of the `args` keyword argument) or a `multiprocessing.Event` to indicate that it should actually start working. This may or may not actually be possible with your use-case, depending on what you need to send to the child process.

However, if you're using Python 3.4+ (or can migrate to 3.4+), you can use the [`spawn` or `forkserver` contexts](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) to avoid having the socket be inherited.

> **spawn**
>
> The parent process starts a fresh python interpreter process.
>   The child process will only inherit those resources necessary to run
>   the process objects run() method. In particular, unnecessary file
>   descriptors and handles from the parent process will not be inherited.
>   Starting a process using this method is rather slow compared to using
>   fork or forkserver.
>
> Available on Unix and Windows. The default on Windows.
>
> **forkserver**
>
> When the program starts and selects the forkserver start
>   method, a server process is started. From then on, whenever a new
>   process is needed, the parent process connects to the server and
>   requests that it fork a new process. The fork server process is single
>   threaded so it is safe for it to use os.fork(). **No unnecessary
>   resources are inherited.**

Example:

```
def _job2():
    for _ in range(3):
        print multiprocessing.current_process(), "is working"
        time.sleep(2)
    print multiprocessing.current_process(), "is done"

ctx = multiprocessing.get_context('forkserver')
worker = ctx.Process(target=_job2)
worker.start()
```

Comment: If only porting wouldn't imply so much work, the forkserver solution works really great. I'll probably accept this solution in a day or two though non of the suggestions fit well with my complex real scenario and time constraints.